# integer = CHARVAR. HINT: no operator matches given name and argument types

Tags: string, postgresql, integer

I'm working on my JAVA swing payroll project and What I'm trying to do is to UPDATE the existing file from my PostgreSQL database

JAVA GUI

Search employee : input the number (1)

and data show up and can EDIT the data and UPDATE it

UPDATE CODE

```
 try {

                String value1 = jTextFirstName.getText();
                String value2 = jTextLastName.getText();
                String value3 = jTextBirthday.getText();
                String value4 = jTextAddress.getText();
                String value5 = jTextPhoneNumb.getText();
                String value6 = jTextStatus.getText();
                String value7 = jTextSSS.getText();
                String value8 = jTextPhilhealth.getText();
                String value9 = jTextTin.getText();
                String value10 = jTextPagibig.getText();
                String value11 = jTextPosition.getText();
                String value12 = jTextSupervisor.getText();
                String value13 = jTextBasicSalary.getText();
                String value14 = jTextRice.getText();
                String value15 = jTextPhone.getText();
                String value16 = jTextClothing.getText();
                String value17 = jTextSemiMonthlyRate.getText();
                String value18 = jTextHourlyRate.getText();
               String value19 = jText_id.getText();
           
                
      pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE register_employee SET first_name=?, last_name=?, bod=?, "
      + "address=?, phone_number=?, status=?, sss=?, philhealth=?, tin=?, pagibig=?, "
      + "job_position=?, supervisor=?, basic_salary=?, rice_allowance=?, phone_allowance=?, "
      + "clothing_allowance=?, gross_semi_monthly_rate=?, hourly_rate=? where id=?");
                
                 pst.setString(1,value1);
                pst.setString(2,value2);
                pst.setString(3,value3);
                pst.setString(4,value4);
                pst.setString(5,value5);
                pst.setString(6,value6);
                pst.setString(7,value7);
                pst.setString(8,value8);
                pst.setString(9,value9);
                pst.setString(10,value10);
                pst.setString(11,value11);
                pst.setString(12,value12);
                pst.setString(13,value13);
                pst.setString(14,value14);
                pst.setString(15,value15);
                pst.setString(16,value16);
                pst.setString(17,value17);
                pst.setString(18,value18);
                pst.setString(19,value19);
        
                
                int k = pst.executeUpdate();
                if(k==1){
                    
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record Updated");
                }
                
             
        }catch(Exception e){
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }finally{
        
            try {
                
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
    }
```

SEARCH EMPLOYEE CODE

```
try {  
pst = conn.prepareStatement("select \* FROM register_employee where id=? ");
int id = Integer.parseInt(txt_search.getText());
pst.setInt(1, id);
ResultSet rs1 = pst.executeQuery();
if(rs1.next()==false)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Sorry Record Not Found");
jTextFirstName.setText("");
jTextLastName.setText("");
jTextBirthday.setText("");
jTextAddress.setText("");
jTextPhoneNumb.setText("");
jTextStatus.setText("");
jTextSSS.setText("");
jTextPhilhealth.setText("");
jTextTin.setText("");
jTextPagibig.setText("");
jTextPosition.setText("");
jTextSupervisor.setText("");
jTextBasicSalary.setText("");
jTextRice.setText("");
jTextPhone.setText("");
jTextClothing.setText("");
jTextSemiMonthlyRate.setText("");
jTextHourlyRate.setText("");
jText_id.requestFocus();
}
else
{
jText_id.setText(rs1.getString("id"));
jTextFirstName.setText(rs1.getString("first_name"));
jTextLastName.setText(rs1.getString("last_name"));
jTextBirthday.setText(rs1.getString("bod"));
jTextAddress.setText(rs1.getString("address"));
jTextPhoneNumb.setText(rs1.getString("phone_number"));
jTextStatus.setText(rs1.getString("status"));
jTextSSS.setText(rs1.getString("sss"));
jTextPhilhealth.setText(rs1.getString("philhealth"));
jTextTin.setText(rs1.getString("tin"));
jTextPagibig.setText(rs1.getString("pagibig"));
jTextPosition.setText(rs1.getString("job_position"));
jTextSupervisor.setText(rs1.getString("supervisor"));
jTextBasicSalary.setText(rs1.getString("basic_salary"));
jTextRice.setText(rs1.getString("rice_allowance"));
jTextPhone.setText(rs1.getString("phone_allowance"));
jTextClothing.setText(rs1.getString("clothing_allowance"));
jTextSemiMonthlyRate.setText(rs1.getString("gross_semi_monthly_rate"));
jTextHourlyRate.setText(rs1.getString("hourly_rate"));

        }
            
            
         }catch(Exception e){
        }
        finally {
    
            try{
                         
    
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                     
    
            }
         }
```

I did try to change the value of "UPDATE register_employee SET into id = '"+value19+"',
and where id=?" to where id = '"+value19+"'  but was not working.

what Im currently understand is Im using a string in my id even though my id is INTEGER. all my data type is VARCHAR.
how to change  integer = CHARVAR.?

Comment: Your `id` field is of type INTEGER, but your Java variables for that field are strings.  You need to use `parseInt` to convert the `jText_id` to integer, and then use `pst.setInt` instead of `pst.setString`.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) Also, stop trying to pretend everything is a string. Your columns should NOT all be VARCHAR, and you should not be reading and writing everything as strings. Use the proper data types for the data, and use the proper methods to read and write them as their actual types. What you're doing now is creating an absolute mess that is going to do nothing but cause you problems. Learn to do things properly, instead of wasting your time.

Comment: Not a java programmer myself, but this smells like SQL injection. Are you sure you want to hackers to destroy your database? Use prepared statements, SQL injection is so 1990's....